# Padding of structure type inside structures

Tags: c, struct, padding

I don't understand the size of struct_b when I am trying to put another struct array of type struct_a in it. I know that the size of struct_a is 16 bytes. But when it comes to struct_b, I assume there should be 2*16 +160=192 bytes, but it actually is 184 bytes. Can you explain it please? Thank you!

```
struct struct_a{
    char id[5];
    float f;
    int n;
};

struct struct_b{
    char name[24];
    struct struct_a array[10];
};
```

Comment: Where did you get 2*16? `name` is 24 bytes.

Comment: the largest type in struct_b is 16 bytes, because 24 >16 ,so I assume there should be a padding?

Answer (score 1):

Because `name` is a `char` type. so it is `1` byte means `1 * 24 = 24 bytes` and sizeof `struct_a` is a 16 bytes. so, `16*10 = 160`.

That's why sizeof `struct_b` is a 184 bytes.

```
24 + 160 = 184 bytes.
```

Comment: Why isn't any padding in struct_b? Like in struct_a, the largest type is 4 btyes, so the character array will occupy 2*4=8 bytes.

Comment: Because there is no need to extra byte. Padding is only inserted when a structure member is followed by a member with a larger alignment requirement.

Comment: I still don't understand, why is the struct_a not having a larger requirement than the char? the former one needs 16 bytes, which is larger than the size of char?

Comment: Padding has nothing to do with the largest member. Padding is inserted to make sure the address of the next member is a multiple of its alignment requirement, which is often, but not always, equal to its size, and usually has an upper limit (often 4 or 8). It depends on the platform, though.
You can usually avoid padding altogether by sorting the members by size (descending).

Comment: @Erlkoenig  _You can usually avoid padding altogether by sorting the members by size (descending)._ That's not correct, Correct statement would be "you can optimize memory utilization by sorting the members by size"